# How to define a copy constructor for a struct that shares a base class and is defined after the struct being defined

Tags: c++, c++17

With two structs `A` and `B`, that subclass the same `Base` struct, I want to have copy constructors for `A` and `B` in struct `A`.

The forward declaration of `B` `struct B;` before struct `A` is defined is the problem, as the compiler does not yet know that B will be subclassing Base.

Is it possible to do a forward declaration like: -

`struct B : public Base;` // Which does not work sadly

The copy constructor in struct 'A' has the error

```
  A(const B& b) : Base{b} {} // Error no matching Base::Base() for const B&.
```

The question is how to do the correct forward declaration for struct `B`.

```
struct Base {
  Base(int value) : _value{value} {}
  Base(const Base& base) : _value{base.value()} {}
  int value() const {return _value;}
private:
  const int _value;
};
struct B; // Compiler does not know that B will subclass Base
struct A : public Base {
  A(int value) : Base{value} {}
  A(const A& a) : Base{a} {}
  A(const B& b) : Base{b} {} // Error no matching Base::Base() for const B&.
};
struct B : public Base {
  B(int value) : Base{value} {}
  B(const B& b) : Base{b} {}
  B(const A& a) : Base{a} {}
};
int main() {
  A a1{20};
  A a2{a1};
  cout << "a1: " << a1.value() << " a2: " << a2.value() << endl;
  B b1{10};
  B b2{b1};
  cout << "b1: " << b1.value() << " b2: " << b2.value() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Added the copy constructor for `A` to struct `B` after sppmacd's answer.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to define them in a .cpp file?

Comment: "I want to have copy constructors for ... `B`" A copy constructor is a particular thing, and it isn't a constructor taking some other type. You can have a "converting constructor" `A::A(const B &)`

Answer (score 3):

Move `A`'s constructor definition out of the class definition, so you can define `B` before using it.

```
struct B;

struct A : Base {
  // ...
  A(const B& b);
};

struct B : Base {
    // ...
};

// ...
A::A(const B& b) : Base{b} {}
```

Note that a constructor that takes an argument of a different type is *not* a copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `struct B` before `struct A`.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I want to do the same thing for struct `B` as well. i.e. a copy constructor for `A` in struct `B`. Was just trying to keep the example simple :-)